# phonegap handle push notification without GCMS or APNS

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a mobile using Sencha touch and phonegap. As per my requirement, I need to implement push notification without using Google Cloud Message Service (GCMS) for android devices and Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for iOS device.

I have gone through pushwoosh plugin and push plugin to implement feature. But these plugins are using GCMS for android and APNS for iOS.

Question: How to implement push notification without using GCMS and APNS. It could be more helpful if I get some information to know how to implement the same from server side also.

Comment: In order to use the built-in notifications for either device you must register the devices through their respective service (GCM, APNS) and send the messages from the server through those services to reach the device. GCM is a simple set-up but APNS requires you to create certificates for SSL. I used these links when doing the same thing https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/ http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Comment: Could you use an [Azure Notification Hub](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)?

Comment: You can create the server or use a built backend for push, but all the options have to use the apple APNs, because they send the push notifications, and your device will only receive them if it comes from the apple APNs

Comment: How about using websockets?

Answer (score 1):

You can't and impossible. You still need APNS and GCM in other to make your push notification works.